# Divvy application not opening or showing any error message

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, macos

The window manager [divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/) is a big part of my workflow. When restarting my macbook yesterday it failed to open entirely. It doesn't give any feedback as to why it's not opening. I tried deleting the app and reinstalling it(via the appstore) to no avail. Was wondering if there was some sort of way to diagnose and fix a stubborn application. I'm on el capitan v10.11.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known problem since 11/10. Update only needs to be approved by Apple. Should be available tomorrow. In the meantime you can use the demo version of the website.

https://twitter.com/MizageApps/status/664712553323335680

In the meantime, the developer recommends that you use the trail version.

https://twitter.com/MizageApps/status/664820916791054336

Comment: Awesome, good to know! Do you have any links to where it says it is a known problem by any chance?

Comment: @anthony-dandrea Updated Dennis' answer with a source.